# NTFS frequent corruption when writing many small files, index $I30 error

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate on a laptop with a 500G HDD, and had all partitions formatted as NTFS. I do a lot of programming and LaTeX typesetting, both of these involves a large amount of reading/writing/deleting to a lot of small files, such as C++ library headers or LaTeX packages.

The problem is that frequently, when there is a large number of writing to files, the partition being written to often corrupts, the `chkntfs e:` returns dirty, where `e:` is the partition being written. I've re-formatted the drive, I've contacted the laptop manufacturer and had the HDD checked, the HDD is not faulty, there are no bad sectors, and I've tried a brand new HDD, to no avail.  The other partition on the **same** physical drive doesn't have this issue.

So at this point I'm pretty sure that it's no hardware related.

I've searched the Microsoft support pages, one page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982018 provides an update for Advanced Format Disks, which I've already installed. The `chkntfs` log shows $130 index errors, and when the `chkdsk` ends I normally lose a lot of files.  What's more strange is that some of the files that I lose aren't even being written to.

I'm at a loss here. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you use to check the hard drive?

Comment: Just because the HD is OK doesn't mean some other piece of hardware isn't failing.  I'd check RAM next.

Comment: @jmreicha I used HD tune and I've sent it to the laptop service center to have it checked.

Comment: Eeeeh....at the point where you know what a C++ header or an index error is, you probably know more than your computer service center's personnel, but I hope it works.

Comment: @afrazier My system comes with 2G RAM, I upgraded it to a single 4G brand new RAM. This is hard to troubleshoot because it is not exactly reproducible.

Comment: @ZacB Yeah, it's a geek shame that I can't solve this seemingly software issue on my own :-) Seriously considering switching to Linux and format the drive as ZFS!

Comment: @afrazier is right: if the productivity loss of this error is messing you up, you should probably just replace the RAM with known-compatible sticks (check your mfr's website). Especially considering how cheap RAM is right now, a new 4GB kit would probably cost less than all the lost time and hassle of troubleshooting less-likely causes of this problem. Also, A+ for ZFS ;)

Comment: I'm the type that doesn't trust what others say, I have to see thing for myself.  Get a copy of [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) and [Drive Fitness Test](http://www.hgst.com/support/index-files/simpletech-legacy-downloads#DFT) and test yourself.

Comment: Questions:  When do you run CHKNTFS E:?  Is there still activity on E:? Do you still have files open on E:?  Have you tried scheduling CHKDSK for boot time to see what it reports?  Have you looked at the system event log to see if there are messages from the disk stack or the file system indicating problems? Lastly, try disabling MSSearch from indexing that drive.  There's a bug in it's interaction with NTFS and newly created files.

Comment: @MJZ When writing to E: fails, I run `chkntfs`, or reboot without running `chkntfs`, and the system just runs chkdsk boot. The boot time CHKDSK reports index $I30 error or BITMAP errors, and the event log is clean. But I'm running MSSearch and I'll disable that to see how this goes. Thanks for the tips!